# Gcov doesn't handle correctly comments and multiple line sentences

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcov, lcov

I am using lcov/gcov to measure test coverages in a project.

However, the test coverage report includes some lines signaled as unhitted that shouldn't be there. For example:

[image]

Comment lines, function definitions splitted across two lines, opening brackets, etc are counted towards total coverage as not covered.

How can I instruct lcov/gcov to ignore such lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue. Looking at gcov man page (https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcov) I found that `gcov works only on code compiled with GCC . It is not compatible with any other profiling or test coverage mechanism.`

Default C compiler in my system was ClangC. Setting `gcc` as compiler when calling `cmake` this way

`$ cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc`

solved the problem.